# How to append selected items to a Kendo MultiSelect One item at a time?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, telerik, kendo-ui, multi-select

I'm using the new Kendo Multi Select Control in Kendo UI version version 2013.1.319. I'm trying to append selected items one at a time and I'm struggling.

My Mark-UP:

```
 <input style="width: 100%; margin-top: 15px;" id="selectedFilters" />
```

My script:

```
 var filterMultiSelect = $('#selectedFilters').kendoMultiSelect({
                        dataSource: data,
                        dataTextField: 'name',
                        dataValueField: 'value',
                        filter: 'contains',
                        placeholder: "No Filters Selected.",
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 2,
                        highlightFirst: true,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        change: function () {
                            applyFilters();
                        }
                    }).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

The script to append the items:

```
newlySelectedFilters.forEach(function (dataItem) {
                        var filters = filterMultiSelect.value();
                        var temp = $.merge($.merge([], filters), [dataItem]);
                        temp = $.unique(temp);
                        filterMultiSelect.value(temp);
                    });
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyhickman/nDmjt/2/) project that illustrates the problem.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a main multi select control that houses all of the filters available  6,000+ i have a combo box (jQuery.ColorBox) with multiple multi select controls on it broken into categories. I want to replace the selected values when going between the main page to the colorbox. It appears to work fine the first time. The second time it fails on the multiselect with 6000+ data items in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok if you find the same problem. Kendo helped me in the [forms](http://www.kendoui.com/forums.aspx/ui/multi-select/how-to-append-a-selected-item-.aspx?actionMode=editPost&postId=69ad806e-9aae-631b-85d4-ff000054ddc5). They created a the following [jsFiddle](http://www.kendoui.com/forums.aspx/ui/multi-select/how-to-append-a-selected-item-.aspx?actionMode=editPost&postId=69ad806e-9aae-631b-85d4-ff000054ddc5). Look at the fiddle. And the usage of the the method .slice() if you want to append the selected values to what is already selected.

The solution is to:

```
// Remove previous selected Filters. (This was undocumented method. I got from Kendo)
multiSelect.dataSource.filter({});

// Set the new filters
filterMultiSelect.value(newlySelectedFilters);
```

resetting the filters in this way resolved my issue.